# DataQuest - Building a unique list in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently doing the tutorials on DataQuest.io.
The goal in the following exercise is to loop through a dataset (flight_delays) and create a list of unique carriers.

```
#setting up empty lists
delays_by_carrier = {}
unique_carriers = []
#formula that returns column number based on column name
carrier_column = column_number_from_name("carrier")

for row in flight_delays:
    if row[carrier_column] in unique_carriers == False:
        unique_carriers.append(row[carrier_column])
print (unique_carriers)
```

The print(unique_carriers) command returns an empty list while I was expecting a list of unique carriers. Can somebody explain/correct?

FYI - I managed to solve the problem by using another approach. I'm still interested to see how I could have fixed this!

Comment: What is flight_delays? A list, dictionary...?

Comment: Flight delays would be a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is the test. You want to check that the carrier is not yet in `unique_carriers` but your test is a bit weird. In any case, you should avoid comparing Boolean values in a test because a test is already a comparison of a Boolean value. The simple expression would be:

```
if row[carrier_column] not in unique_carriers:
    ...
```

What you wanted to write was:

```
if (row[carrier_column] in unique_carriers) == False:
    ...
```

That would have worked (but is inelegant). You could also write `not (row[carrier_column] in unique_carriers)`.

What is interesting in your question is what actually happens. This is not an issue about operator priority: your code is not interpreted as `row[carrier_column] in (unique_carriers == False)`, that would raise a `TypeError` exception stating that you cannot use the `in` operator with a Boolean.

No, what happens is that in Python, you can [chain comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) such as `x < y < z`, and `in` and `==` are both comparisons in that sense. Therefore your statement was interpreted as `(row[carrier_column] in unique_carriers) and (unique_carriers == False)`.

You can confirm it with the bytecode. Here I do a simple function to look at what Python will do with it:

```
>>> def f():
...     if row[carrier_column] in unique_carriers == False:
...         pass
...
```

And then, let's look at bytecode!

```
>>> dis.dis(f)
2         0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (row)
          3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (carrier_column)
          6 BINARY_SUBSCR
          7 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (unique_carriers)
         10 DUP_TOP
         11 ROT_THREE
         12 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
         15 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    27
         18 LOAD_CONST               1 (False)
         21 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
         24 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 29)
    >>   27 ROT_TWO
         28 POP_TOP
    >>   29 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       35

3        32 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 35)
    >>   35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         38 RETURN_VALUE
```

At `10` you see the `DUP_TOP` that duplicates the top of the stack which, at that time, is the list. Then the `ROT_THREE` rotates the stack such that you end up with:

```
unique_carriers
row[carrier_column]
unique_carriers
```

Now you get the first comparison using `in` (`12`) which, if `True` continues to `18` and `21` to compare what remains (`unique_carriers` since the other 2 have been popped in the comparison) with `False`. That's it, your test is:

```
if row[carrier_column] in unique_carriers:
    if unique_carriers == False:
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. To resume, the following solutions would have worked:

```
if row[carrier_column] not in unique_carriers:
```

---

```
if (row[carrier_column] in unique_carriers) == False:
```

The explanation on why my code didn't work kind of got over my head. But I now understand the complexity of the test I created ensuring that I will try to find an elegant solution first.

Kind regards